# UINavigationController - set title does not work if view is inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have in my AppDelegate a `UINavigationController` called `navController`.
Normally, I can set the title of it with

```
self.navController.title = @"My title";
```

But now I have a view with a `UIScrollView` and I add in this scroll view subviews:

```
[myScrollView addSubview:myController.view];
```

In these subviews with ViewControllers I try to do to set the title in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, but without success, the title remains empty in the screen.
The `UIScrollView` is used to swipe between the pages horizontally combined with a `UIPageControl`.

But how can I set the title of the navigation controller in my case? (Every page change, I want to change the title to the title I set in the associated view controller)

Best Regards Tim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do only `self.title = @"title";`

Comment: Yes, this works in the top view controller but not inside the view controllers which are added as a subview.

Comment: Yes, I have to do this in the parent `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pointer to the nav controller like this

```
self.navigationController.title = @"title";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You see, I already did this. Normally it does work, but not embedding the ViewController in a ScrollView and add it as a subview.

Comment: Hmmm. self.topViewController.navigationController.title should work then depending on exactly where you're calling it from.

Comment: Make sure you're typing it exactly like this. navigationController is not your properties name.

Comment: Yes, I also tried `navigationController`, but no success. `Property 'topViewController' not found on object of type 'MyViewController1 *'; did you mean 'modalViewController'?` I tried it in `viewDidLoad`, perhaps it is loaded too late? The view controllers does not have a `UINavigationController`, because they are only loaded inside a scrollview, I think that could be the problem? In my other ViewControllers I do `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController1 animated:YES];` and then it works with the navigation title.

Comment: Oops. I meant parentViewController.

Comment: `self.parentViewController.title = @"test"` does not work... also `self.parentViewController.navigationController.title = @"test"`

Comment: Then maybe you can post some code showing where you're calling this from and where that is in your view hierarchy.

Comment: I have a navigationController and I am one level under the top level. In this level I have a horizontal navigation with a ScrollView. The ScrollView is inside of a ViewController and it embeds other ViewControllers. So I have not a direct access to the navigationController. And this should be the problem...

Comment: Inside the ViewController I have the scrollView and there I add the subviews: `[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];` and in these subviewcontrollers I want to set the title of the navigationController.

Comment: Hm, I can set the title in the ViewController which do the addSubview of the other controllers with `self.title`, because this ViewController manages the subviews which are loaded into the scrollview. But how can I access the title from the subviews?

Comment: You could pass the navigation controller as a property to each of the sub view controllers but there is probably a better way to do it. Good question :)

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution, but not very nice as you already mentioned. Anyone an idea?

Comment: @Tim. Can you try this for me... self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title. I tried this in something I was working on and seemed to work.

Comment: I have to do it inside the `ViewController` in which I do the `addSubview`, otherwise it is not possible.